# killing screen but java process not ending

Tags: java, bash, gnu-screen, kill-process

I am running a script that basically runs a bunch of servers for local testing.

These jars are run in different screens because they need to all independently accept keyboard input.  To do this I used screen.

```
command1="java -jar $fullPath"
screen -d -m -S "${screenName[$i]}" bash -c "$command1"
```

It worked great!

then I needed a way to kill all of the servers

so I wrote a script that does that

```
for session in $(screen -ls | grep -o "[0-9]*\.${screenName[$i]}")
do
    screen -X -S "$session" quit
    echo "killing screen $session"
done
```

It works great the screens are killed.
BUT the second I do that java all of a sudden take up 100% of my CPU.

Before I use the quit screen command

[image: The servers running normally]

After I use the quit screen command

[image]

They also take forever to kill through the gui using force quit

[image]

Other info:

- The servers are using Jetty which run on one java thread. and then another thread just sits and waits for keyboard input.
- Obviously this is running on mac and the script is in bash so I would like a bash solution that works for mac and linux.
- Also they are built using java 7 but run using java 8

because the servers are accepting keyboard input all commands sent to screen are ingested by the servers.
They do have input that quits them but I don't want to trust the servers to quit.

So my questions are:

- **Is there a way to have a screen terminate all running processes in it when it terminates?**
- **if not is there a way to send the ctrl-c to a specific screen?**
- **If not is there a way to see what the running process of a certain screen is without running commands in the screen itself? (then I can just use kill)**

tl;dr when I kill screen the running process starts using all my cpu and does not terminate. I want it to terminate.

Comment: You could kill every Java program by calling `killall -9 java`.

Comment: Okay good idea I will use as the worst case solution as it kills any other java programs I have running...
But it does prevent me playing minecraft when I am supposed to be working :P

But hopefully a solution that only kills these specific servers comes. :)

Comment: If you find a way to determine the process id of your `screen` process (or even better store them as you spawn them) you might be able to use the `-ppid` option of `ps` to kill all processes spawned by the `screen` processes.

Comment: I found a way to get the id of the screen process but the command
    `$(ps -ppid $pid)`
says `ps: Invalid process id: pid`

Comment: exact same problem here, did you find out why it is taking 100% cpu?

Comment: no :(
Just had to solve it myself with the below answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Made the solution myself.

In a nutshell it finds the screen process and finds all java processes then looks for a java process whose grandparent process is a screen.

It is extremely inefficient as it loops through the array for every screen.  So basically O(n^2) but there are very few so it works for me!

Code:

```
length=$(expr ${#screenName[@]} - 1)

# gets all of the java processes and their grand parents
# the reason is that the screen makes 2 processes one is the java process and the other is the parent process
# I can't grab a children in mac for some reason BUT i can grab the parent process
javaPs=()
javaGpPs=()
for javaId in $(pgrep java)
do
    #echo
    #echo $javaId
    #echo $(ps -o ppid= $javaId)
    #echo $(ps -o ppid= $(ps -o ppid= $javaId))
    javaPs+=($javaId)
    javaGpPs+=($(ps -o ppid= $(ps -o ppid= $javaId)))
done

echo "Child procressed followed by screen processes"
echo ${javaPs[@]}
echo ${javaGpPs[@]}
#gets the index of an element in an array
#search term is first followed by the array
#note that becuase it returns by echo you can not add any debug statements into this function
search() {
    local i=1;
    searchTerm="${1}"
    shift #moves over the argument looking
    array=("${@}") #grabs the rest of the args as an array (which is an array)
    for str in ${array[@]}; do
        if [ "$str" = "$searchTerm" ]; then
            echo $((i - 1)) #should reference the correct index (0 to something)
            return
        else
            ((i++))
        fi
    done
    echo "-1"
}

for (( i=0; i<=$length; i++ ))
do
    #looks to see if there are multiple screens with the same name
    for session in $(screen -ls | grep -o "[0-9]*\.${screenName[$i]}")
    do
        echo
        echo "killing screen $session"
        IFS='.' read -ra ADDR <<< "$session" #splits the id from the name
        pid=${ADDR[0]}
        screen -X -S "$session" quit # exit session

        # now we kill the still running java process (because it will not exist for some reason)
        itemIndex=$(echo $(search "${pid}" "${javaGpPs[@]}"))
        javaId=${javaPs[$itemIndex]}
        # the process that is being killed
        echo "killing java process"
        echo $(ps -p $javaId)
        kill -9 $javaId
        sleep 1
    done
done

echo
echo "All process should now be dead doing extra clean up now"
screen -wipe #remove all dead screens
```